# md127 : inactive sdb

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

I tried to fresh install a  ubuntu on an server but it failed stating inactive sdb. Shared below is the stat. I am not familiar with RAID and wondering if someone could guide me on how to fix it ?

```
root@eve-ng:/dev# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid0] [linear] [multipath] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md126 : active raid0 sdb[0]
      976224256 blocks super external:/md127/1 64k chunks

md127 : inactive sdb[0](S)
      538328 blocks super external:ddf

unused devices: <none>
root@eve-ng:/dev#
```

Comment: Did you copy type this? Are you sure about both instances of `sdb`?

Comment: Did you look up the error to see what it might indicate?